# Bounty removal request

Tags: support

Can we have the bounty removed from [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/968131/why-are-us-based-azure-regions-priced-differently) so that we can close it please? The question is the epitome of a bad question that is unanswerable and is attracting some [truly bad](https://serverfault.com/a/968598/9517) answers ;) Only one of the 5 that are currently there is even positive.

I don't see how this is even vaguely topical for SF. Why $company prices $product the way that it does is not a practical system administration issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't know how to revoke a bounty before this, but now I do...

I expect you and the other commentors to throw some close votes on it if you feel it deserves it.

Comment: Thank you! I already tried to close it but was stymied by the bounty.

Comment: Unrelated: did you see my friend Pauric today  https://www.strava.com/activities/2390817238 :)